# Google Apps Script: Scriplets on HTML Template

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm looking for a way to add a section inside my Html template that will be conditionally shown.

I've been looking at scriptlets but all the examples I found were related to "for" functions.

This is my code so far

```
<tbody>
<? console.log("assigment_letter: " + assigment_letter)?>
<? assigment_letter == "" ? ?>
<tr style="font-size:14px;text-align:center;color:black">
<td style="padding:5px 40px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">Assigment Letter</td>
<td style="padding:5px 40px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">NOT FOUND</td>
</tr>
<? : "" ?>    
</tbody>
```

In the console log I'm validating that indeed the value from the variable assigment letter is blank and depending on that, I'd like to show a new row inside the table I'm buidling.

However I'm getting the following error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
> at RejectedRequestEmail(Rejected Email:16:49)
> at onChange(Code:691:11)

It does not tell me exactly in which line of the Html the evaluate function is getting the error

Here is my function that evalutes this html template in case needed

```
function RejectedRequestEmail(email_obj){
  const htmlTemplateAgent = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email Reject Notification');
  htmlTemplateAgent.requesting_user_name = email_obj.requesting_user_name;
  htmlTemplateAgent.invoice_id = email_obj.invoice_id;
  htmlTemplateAgent.client_name = email_obj.client_name;
  htmlTemplateAgent.beneficiary_name = email_obj.beneficiary_name;
  htmlTemplateAgent.invoice_amount = email_obj.invoice_amount;
  htmlTemplateAgent.assigment_letter = email_obj.assigment_letter;
  htmlTemplateAgent.invoice_product_match = email_obj.invoice_product_match;
  htmlTemplateAgent.prohibited_items = email_obj.prohibited_items;
  htmlTemplateAgent.client_verified = email_obj.client_verified;
  htmlTemplateAgent.beneficiary_verified = email_obj.beneficiary_verified;
  htmlTemplateAgent.bank_verified = email_obj.bank_verified;
  htmlTemplateAgent.reviewer_name = email_obj.reviewer_name;
  
  const htmlForNotification = htmlTemplateAgent.evaluate().getContent();     
  
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

When you want to use the ternary operator, how about the following modification? In this modification, the scriptlet of `<?!= ... ?>` is used.

```html
<tbody>
<? console.log("assigment_letter: " + assigment_letter)?>
<?!= assigment_letter == "" ? `<tr style="font-size:14px;text-align:center;color:black">
<td style="padding:5px 40px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">Assigment Letter</td>
<td style="padding:5px 40px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">NOT FOUND</td>
</tr>` : "" ?>
</tbody>
```

Or, when you want to use the if statement, how about the following modification? In this modification, the scriptlet of `<? ... ?>` is used.

```html
<tbody>
<? console.log("assigment_letter: " + assigment_letter)?>
<? if (assigment_letter == "") { ?>
<tr style="font-size:14px;text-align:center;color:black">
<td style="padding:5px 40px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">Assigment Letter</td>
<td style="padding:5px 40px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">NOT FOUND</td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</tbody>
```

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: thanks Tanaike, I'll test it out and come back with news

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying. When my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Couldn't make it work with the ternary operator but the second option worked for me:) Thanks Tanaike!